# openldap allop overlay configuration

Tags: openldap

I'm having trouble getting the allop overlay to work.  I suspect I'm missing some vital configuration option or that I've done something incorrectly.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

I need to use allop to get a cisco device working with ldap using the memberOf attribute.  I've already got the memberOf overlay working correctly and memberOf attribute is returned when I query with '+'.

I've installed openldap 2.4.28 on my Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS server using apt-get install.  I compiled the allop overlay from source and copied the allop.so library to the /var/lib/ldap/ directory.

This version of openldap uses the olc config method.

I added the module using the following ldif:

```
## module.ldif
dn: cn=module,cn=config
cn: module
objectclass: olcModuleList
objectclass: top
olcmoduleload: allop.so
olcmodulepath: /usr/lib/ldap
# sudo ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f module.ldif -v
```

I added the overlay configuration using the following ldif:

```
## allop.ldif
dn: olcOverlay={2}allop,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcConfig
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: top
olcOverlay: {2}allop
# sudo ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f allop.ldif -v
```

I then restarted slapd and tested, but the operational attributes are still not returned.

Here is some of the output from running slapd with debug Trace:

```
54198057 ldif_read_file: read entry file: "/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=module{3}.ldif"
54198057 => str2entry: "# AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
# CRC32 18d7a995
dn: cn=module{3}
objectClass: olcModuleList
objectClass: top
cn: module{3}
olcModulePath: /usr/lib/ldap
olcModuleLoad: {0}allop.so
structuralObjectClass: olcModuleList
entryUUID: 1e7b5ebe-d252-1033-97f7-618a755f5e4b
creatorsName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
createTimestamp: 20140917010302Z
entryCSN: 20140917010302.779622Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
modifyTimestamp: 20140917010302Z
"
54198057 >>> dnPrettyNormal: <cn=module{3}>
54198057 <<< dnPrettyNormal: <cn=module{3}>, <cn=module{3}>
54198057 >>> dnNormalize: <gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth>
54198057 <<< dnNormalize: <gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth>
54198057 >>> dnNormalize: <gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth>
54198057 <<< dnNormalize: <gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth>
54198057 <= str2entry(cn=module{3}) -> 0x7f04f45450c8

...

54198057 ldif_read_file: read entry file: "/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}hdb/olcOverlay={2}allop.ldif"
54198057 => str2entry: "# AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
# CRC32 1b6fab9c
dn: olcOverlay={2}allop
objectClass: olcConfig
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: top
olcOverlay: {2}allop
structuralObjectClass: olcOverlayConfig
entryUUID: 5c207c24-d25a-1033-8da6-db55e5b2e477
creatorsName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
createTimestamp: 20140917020202Z
entryCSN: 20140917020202.176575Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
modifyTimestamp: 20140917020202Z
"
54198057 >>> dnPrettyNormal: <olcOverlay={2}allop>
54198057 <<< dnPrettyNormal: <olcOverlay={2}allop>, <olcOverlay={2}allop>
54198057 >>> dnNormalize: <gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth>
54198057 <<< dnNormalize: <gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth>
54198057 >>> dnNormalize: <gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth>
54198057 <<< dnNormalize: <gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth>
54198057 <= str2entry(olcOverlay={2}allop) -> 0x7f04f45450c8
```

There's nothing interesting in the debug output when I run the query, certainly no error messages or anything related to allop.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention it in your configuration, but have you got the 'allop-URI' option configured? If left blank it will only return operational attributes for `ldap:///??base` - that is, a base of "" and a scope "base".  You will need to specify a pattern for which it should return the operational attributes, such as `ldap:///??sub`

Note that allop-URI doesn't do particular operational attributes - it's all or nothing for the scope and base provided.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by moving from OLC to slapd.conf configuration.  It seems there is no OLC support for allop.